# Django ArrayField. How to save nested array of time?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Question is stupid, by i cant find solution. What a valid format for saving nested array of time from simple form text field?

I have ArrayField like this:

```
schedule = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            ArrayField(
                models.TimeField(null=True),
            ),
            size=2,
            null=True,
        ),
        size=7,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

When i am trying to save it from django admin like:

```
((09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 09:00), (09:00, 9:00), (9:00, 9:00), (9:00, 9:00))
```

I'm getting errors

```
Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 1 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 2 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 3 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 4 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 5 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 6 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 7 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 8 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 9 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 10 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 11 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 12 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
Item 13 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Item 0 in the array did not validate: Enter a valid time.
```

Comment: pass array of string `(('09:00', '09:00'),...)` add quotes to time string.

Comment: any proper solution found?

Comment: @Sindbag Still no solution, I just switched to JSON field instead of ArrayField.

Comment: @umaru I just updated save method to recombine the input array into proper tuples :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't save time in string format. You have to use python's [DateTime library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to create a time object.

And you can't save it using a tuple of tuples. Use a simple list like this:

```
[time_object_1, time_object_2, time_object_3]
```

Also, if you are using Django Admin, don't give spaces between the objects, else it will give the same error.

[image]

If you remove the spaces the error will be resolved like this:

[image]